# TYPO3 rte didn't render <p> tag in extension output view

Tags: php, typo3

I have some problem with `rte` in my extension. In tables I set field `text area with rte`. In BE TYPO3 generating rte view and when I formatting text everything is ok. The only problem is when I have some paragraphs - in BE I have `<p>` tag, but in frontend in HTML code the `<p>` tag didn't "exist".

My TCA code looks like this:

```
'description' => array(     
        'exclude' => 1,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:fu_product_table/locallang_db.xml:tx_table_products.description',       
        'defaultExtras' => 'richtext[*]',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => '30',
            'rows' => '5',
            'wizards' => array(
                '_PADDING' => 2,
                'RTE' => array(
                    'notNewRecords' => 1,
                    'RTEonly'       => 1,
                    'type'          => 'script',
                    'title'         => 'Full screen Rich Text Editing|Formatteret redigering i hele vinduet',
                    'icon'          => 'wizard_rte2.gif',
                    'script'        => 'wizard_rte.php',
                ),
            ),
        )
      ),
```

And then trying to render the field in the class:

```
'<td class="td-1">' . $this->getFieldContent('description') . '</td>';
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: How do you display the field in frontend ?

Comment: `<td class="td-1" >' . $this->getFieldContent('description') . '</td>`, but others tags display, like `<br />`

Comment: check this pls: `$this->pi_RTEcssText($this->getFieldContent('description'))`

Comment: working like a charm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TYPO3 saves RTE's content little bit 'trimmed' (without full markup) so for 'reverting' it back to the valid HTML you need to wrap it with the dedicated method, ie:

```
$this->pi_RTEcssText($this->getFieldContent('description'))
```

Note: Adrian, next point for Extbase: it has special viewhelper for this, so you can do it easily directly in the template ;)

Comment: I'm trying to start with extbase and fluid. Is anything similar like Kickstarter for that extbase technology?

Comment: Of course: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder - important choose `2.4.7` for TYPO3 v. 4 OR `2.5.0+` for TYPO3 v. 6+

Comment: Thanks Biesior for info - I will try if I found some free time